# Cococs2d and Arc

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, automatic-ref-counting

I've just begun developing with Cocos2d for iPhone. And I've realized that there was no "Use Automatic Reference Counting" check box when creating a new project with a Cocos2d template. My Xcode is 4.3.1, iOS 5. Can I still omit retains and releases or do I have to go old style?

Comment: I think the newest version supports ARC. Either that or one of the v2 betas does. I know I read it somewhere :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to enable ARC under Build Settings before you can use it. For cocos2d you need at least v1.0.1 (with possibly some manual fixes) or v1.1 or v2.0. Then follow my [tutorial about enabling ARC in a cocos2d project](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/04/enabling-arc-cocos2d-project-howto-stepbystep-tutorialguide/).

You could also just [use Kobold2D for cocos2d development](http://www.kobold2d.com). ARC is already enabled in all template projects.

Comment: Yeah, I've watched your video tutorial. It was a bit complicated that's why I decided to apply to SO. But you caught me here again. Thank you.

Comment: Also, I simplified the description for the 3rd edition of the Learn Cocos2D book, which will use ARC for all projects. I'll release project templates with already ARC-enabled cocos2d projects soon, they'll be a free download.